Column annotations using pheatmap in R
I am trying to annotate my heatmap of gene expression data with the function of the gene, but I want to customize the colors of the annotation.  My code works, but it is still using the default colors for the column annotation.
Relevant portion of the code:
name_function_matrix <- str_split_fixed(colnames(transposedData), "_", 2)
    gene_col <- data.frame(row.names = name_function_matrix[,1], gene_function = name_function_matrix[,2])
    
    colnames(transposedData) <- rownames(gene_col)
    
    col_groups <- as.data.frame(unique(name_function_matrix[,2]))
    
    
    gene_col_colors <- list(group = "blue","green","cyan","gray","red")
    
    names(gene_col_colors$group) <- col_groups

Update:  I'm pretty sure the dimensions of my color/gene_function matrix are incorrect, but I don't know how pheatmaps reads it in when i assign it using annotation_col =
full code:
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(pheatmap)
library(dendsort)
library(RColorBrewer)

Data <- read.table("PathToFile/Data.txt",sep="\t",header=TRUE, quote="", fill = TRUE)
row.names(Data) <- Data$gene

Data <- Data[, -1]

FilteredData = Data %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), function(x) x <=-3 | x >=3))

dim(Data)
dim(FilteredData)

transposedData = t(FilteredData)


sort_hclust <- function(...) as.hclust(dendsort(as.dendrogram(...)))

df_cluster_cols <- sort_hclust(hclust(dist(t(transposedData))))
df_cluster_rows <- sort_hclust(hclust(dist(t(transposedData))))

clrsp <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "black", "yellow"))   
clrs <- clrsp(10) 

breaks1 <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 10)

name_function_matrix <- str_split_fixed(colnames(transposedData), "_", 2)
gene_col <- data.frame(row.names = name_function_matrix[,1], gene_function = name_function_matrix[,2])

colnames(transposedData) <- rownames(gene_col)

col_groups <- as.data.frame(unique(name_function_matrix[,2]))


gene_col_colors <- list(group = "blue","green","cyan","gray","red")

names(gene_col_colors$group) <- col_groups

print(gene_col_colors)

pheatmap(transposedData, 
         clustering_distance_rows = "correlation",
         clustering_distance_cols = "euclidean",
         cluster_rows = TRUE,                       
         cluster_cols = TRUE, 
         #cluster_rows = df_cluster_rows,
         #cluster_cols = df_cluster_cols,
         #display_numbers = TRUE,
         #fontsize = 2,
         annotation_col = gene_col,
         annotation_colors  = gene_col_colors,
         clustering_method = "centroid",
         show_rownames = TRUE, 
         show_colnames = FALSE,
         scale = "none",
         color = clrs,
         breaks = breaks1,
         cellwidth = 0.2,
         cellheight = 10,
         fontsize = 5,
         fontsize_row = 5,
         fontsize_col = 3,
         treeheight_col = 0,
         treeheight_row = 20,
         #legend_breaks = -10:10,
         filename = "PathToFile/imageX.png")

Here is a link to my datafile:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xUkswrzcgdPellHqjR3ePN__zmox8F6r/view?usp=drive_link

If you want to specify the colours of the column annotations in your heatmap you can define a colour palette for the gene_functionannotations and then pass this information into pheatmap. A suggestion on how you could update your code:
Create a color palette for every unique function in gene_function
Make a list of annotation_colors and set it to annotation_colors in pheatmap.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
